# How to display the Text in bottom of the screen?

Tags: java, android

In android app i have display the score in TextView in bottom of the screen, It has displayed in emulator but not display in phone. i changed to display in top of the screen it has work in phone 
but i need to display in bottom of the screen in phone.

Please any one give idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)? Note that this will work only in a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: No i didn't try. But I have using RelativeLayout. now i will try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_iphone" >

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using `RelativeLayout` to position text at the top, middle, and bottom of the display.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with attribute align_parent_bottom

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```